# SQL Date datatype query

Tags: mysql, date, phpmyadmin

when I run

```
 INSERT INTO `table 4`(`COL 5`, `COL 6`) VALUES ([STR_TO_DATE(`7/11/2014`,
`%m/%d/%Y`)],[STR_TO_DATE(`7/18/2014`,`%m/%d/%Y`)])
```

I get

```
#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '[STR_TO_DATE(`7/11/2014`,`%m/%d/%Y`)],
[STR_TO_DATE(`7/18/2014`,`%m/%d/%Y`)])' Ã  la ligne 1
```

Is there any other way to format string to date? Or should I go ahead this way with some modifications. I already have 2 columns with data type varchar and dates are in the format (mm/dd/yyyy). I need to perform subtraction between them to get the no. of days. Cant do that when its in the varchar format.

Comment: did you copy that? then the mistake is that you are not using `'` but ` probably because you first wrote your query in word or something?

Comment: and if you did it just to show us the formatting, then the problem is that they are missing for all strings, e.g. `'7/11/2014'` and `'%m/%d/%Y'`

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. please tag appropriate products only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What needs to happen:**

1. [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is expecting single quotes "'" around the date and formatting parameters.
2. Table 4 is not a valid table name without "`"
3. Remove brackets around STR_TO_DATE functions

   [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b87e/1/0)

**Before**

```
INSERT INTO table 4(COL 5, COL 6) VALUES ([STR_TO_DATE(7/11/2014,%m/%d/%Y)],[STR_TO_DATE(7/18/2014,%m/%d/%Y)])
```

**After**

```
INSERT INTO `table 4`(`COL 5`, `COL 6`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('7/11/2014','%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('7/18/2014','%m/%d/%Y'))
```